# How to Resize google reCAPTCHA?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, recaptcha

The image of the problem:

[image]

The code:

```
<div class="text-xs-center" id="DIVCATCHA" runat="server">
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnImageSelected" />
  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="" style="transform:scale(0.81);-webkit-transform:scale(0.81);transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0;" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try removing your custom `style` attribute?

Comment: yes, but the problem still continue , thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

By using the CSS transform property you can achieve changing the width by changing the entire scale of the reCAPTCHA.

By adding in just two inline styles, you can make the reCAPTCHA fit nicely:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" 
     data-theme="light" 
     data-sitekey="XXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
     style="transform:scale(0.77);transform-origin:0 0">
</div>
```

More details can be found here: https://www.geekgoddess.com/how-to-resize-the-google-nocaptcha-recaptcha/